# For a given $r$, finding $p,q$ such that $p^{\frac{q-1}{r}}=1\pmod q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The following is a part of a problem from Marcus's Number Fields, which has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1593913/672301) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2796828/672301):

a) Show that there exist primes $p,q$ such that $p$ splits into $r$ distinct primes in the $q-$th cyclotomic field $K.$

We know that number of prime factors in the splitting of $p$ in $\mathbb{\zeta_q}=r=\frac{q-1}{f}$,where $f$ is the order of $p$ modulo $q$(here we are assuming $p\ne q$). Thus we have to find two pairs of prime numbers $(p,q)$ such that order of $p$ modulo $q$ is $\frac{q-1}{r}$. But this looks hard to do, so I was wondering if it is the correct way to approach. If not, a hint towards the correct direction will be appreciated.

There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2331991/672301) to a similar question, which is not satisfying to me.

Comment: There's a difference between "find" and "prove such $(p,q)$ exist."

Comment: What dou you mean by $\zeta_q=r=\frac{q-1}f?$ Don't abuse the equals sign this way.

Comment: I think your reduction to the question "Find $p,q$ such that $p$ has order $\frac{q-1}{r}$ mod $q$" is a step towards the right answer. Indeed, now you just need to argue that there exists some $q$ such that $r\mid q-1$, and use that for any divisor of $q-1$, there exists an element mod $q$ with that order. Then argue why a prime must exist in this residue class.

Comment: One way to do both of these arguments is to use Dirichlets theorem on arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Does this idea help?

$$p^{\frac {q-1}r}=kq+1$$

$$[(p-1)+1]^{q-1}=(kq+1)^r$$

$$m(p-1)(q-1)=n(r)(kq)$$

$(q, q-1)=1$

1)Suppose $(m, n, p-1)=1$, then we must have:

$\begin{cases}q|p-1\\ r|q-1\end{cases}$

2)Suppose $(m,n, q-1)=1$, then we must have:

$\begin{cases}r|p-1\\ q|q-1\end{cases}$

These can be the conditions for p and q for a give r.